# Regex: Delete over Multiple Ending With A Line Continuation Character

Tags: regex, vim

I am looking for a regex expression that will delete text over multiple lines, and only stop once a line does not **end** with a special "line continuation" character, the backslash.

```
some_other_text_1

 device_1 \|node1 node2 node3 \
   setting1 setting2 setting3 \
   setting4 setting5

some_other_text_2

 device_2 \|node1 node2 node3 \
   setting1 setting2 setting3

some_other_text_3
```

The resulting output should be:

```
some_other_text_1


some_other_text_2

device_2 \|node1 node2 node3 \
   setting1 setting2 setting3

some_other_text_3
```

I am running this as a find and replace command using vim.

So far I have tried:

```
%/^\s*.device_1\_.\{-}\(\\\)\@!
```

But this only runs until the first backslash.

Comment: t̶r̶y̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶g̶e̶x̶ ̶d̶e̶b̶u̶g̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶r̶e̶g̶e̶x̶1̶0̶1̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶

Comment: @ChrismonChin Why? regex101 does not support Vim regex syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my fault, didn't read into it well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\_.\{-}\(\\\)\@!` part only matches any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first location not followed with a backslash.

You need to match any number of lines that end with `\`, and the next line.

Use

```
%s/^\s*device_1.*\(\n.*\\$\)*\n.*//
```

- `^` - line start
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `device_1` - a literal string
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\(\n.*\\$\)*` - 0 or more sequences of a line break and then a line ending with `\`
- `\n.*` - a line break and any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Comment: FYI: To also remove the line break after the match, add `\n?` at the end of the pattern.